# How can I use unicorn as "rails s"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

A new Rails project's `Gemfile` shows:

```
# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'
```

`rails s --help` shows:

```
Usage: rails server [mongrel, thin, etc] [options]
```

Yet, doing:

```
rails s unicorn
```

I get:

```
/Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/unicorn (LoadError)
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in `try_require'
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@keynote/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've used unicorn in the past on other projects, but always had to run the `unicorn` command and specify a config file which is a bit of a pain.  I am wondering how I can just simply make it work by using `rails s...`

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think `unicorn` can be called from `rails server` directly. Check this out - https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails

Comment: Just typing `unicorn` works for me, same amount of keystrokes as `rails s`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It looks like the [`unicorn-rails`](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails) gem that @Dogbert mentioned can actually be used to make Unicorn the `rails server` handler.

Simply include `gem "unicorn-rails"` (and for Rails 4.2.4, `gem "rack-handlers"`) in your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` to install the gem, then you can run:

```
$ rails server unicorn
```

Although once `unicorn-rails` is installed, Unicorn should be the default app server so you could also just run `rails server` and it should use Unicorn (assuming you don't also have Thin or Mongrel in your `Gemfile`, in which case they may conflict and you might want to remove the ones you're not using).

Comment: I find it very interesting that the gemfile has 'unicorn' rather than 'unicorn_rails' as a suggestion.  I also find it interesting that this webpage says:  "unicorn_rails was made to be an easier transition for users of pre-Rack versions of Rails. The manpage encourages Rails 3 users to use plain unicorn instead."  http://blog.engineyard.com/2010/everything-you-need-to-know-about-unicorn

Comment: Which Gemfile are you seeing `unicorn` in? I suggested adding the `unicorn-rails` gem to your Gemfile.

Comment: For Rails 4.2.4, this first requires adding `gem 'rack-handlers'` to your Gemfile along with `gem 'unicorn'`

Comment: To whomever stumbles upon this: `unicorn-rails` breaks with `rack` versions >=3. The gem seems unmaintained at this point in time.

Answer (score 27):

A better option might just be to run the unicorn server directly.

```
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 # default port is 8080
```

Comment: How can i increase Workers?

Answer (score 19):

```
gem 'rack-handlers'

rails server unicorn
```

Comment: The other beauty of using rack-handlers is that it autoloads the config/unicorn.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

However the answer by `Steven` is the simplest way to do.

I  run `unicorn` on development environment via a rake task:

lib/tasks/dev_unicorn.rake:

```
task :server do
  # optional port parameter
  port = ENV['PORT'] ? ENV['PORT'] : '3000'
  puts 'start unicorn development'
  # execute unicorn command specifically in development
  # port at 3000 if unspecified
  sh "cd #{Rails.root} && RAILS_ENV=development unicorn -p #{port}"
end
# an alias task
task :s => :server
```

run:

`rake s`

*Reference [http://jing.io](http://jing.io/t/use-unicorn-as-Rails-3-development-server.html)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use unicorn as 'rails s'. Use this -

Add gem 'unicorn' to gem file and run bundle install.

and then run any of the following commands -

$ unicorn -p 3000

or

$ unicorn_rails -p 3000