# How to speed up Rails Development Environment and avoid spinning up

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I have an application demo coming up soon and I need my development environment to be a bit faster than it currently is.  I'm running a Rails 3.2.19 app with Ruby 1.9.3, Postgres, and Anvil/Pow to serve on a Apple Mac Mini (Core i5/4g ram) and need to be able to demo the application with decent response times.

In production, the app runs very fast but in development it's more sluggish and at times if I let the app sit idle and hit another URL it takes up to a minute for the app to spin up again.

I'm wondering if it's a problem with Pow and that I should instead just run a local `rails s` instance to spin up the environment.  The main issue I'm seeing is that when the app sits idle for a while (let's say an hour or so) when I go to hit a url or resource within the app it can take up to a minute for the app to respond again.

Is there something I'm missing here that would allow me to prevent the latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal opinion is to ditch Pow and go with [Unicorn](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicorn) or [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) or [Puma](http://puma.io) but for the love of all that's good do not use the built-in, default of WEBrick :)!

I use Unicorn locally (it's also what we use on our production boxes) and my local sites are as fast or faster than production.

I started out with Pow but ran into a lot little 'issues' like you've mentioned and have been happy since switching to [run Unicorn as my Rails development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858887/how-can-i-use-unicorn-as-rails-s).

Comment: I like Pow/Anvil because of the .dev domains it gives you which is really nice but the performance hit is harsh.  Come to find out, I didn't realize it but I already had thin in my `Gemfile`.  So I did a `bundle exec thin start` and boy is it much faster than webbrick or Pow.  Should I relocate the thin gem to my development group?  Apparently I've had it in my main `Gemfile` as a production gem all this time and didn't realize it.  Also, does thin have the issue with spindown after a while?

Comment: Thin doesn't have to be in the development group but, I think, it's advisable to put it in that group if it is not your production server (since we use Unicorn on both, I let my gem entry for it be intermingled with the others and not in a dedicated group). For the .dev domain, which I love too, you can easily do that on your Mac. Just edit /private/etc/hosts and add this to a new line: 0.0.0.0   www.mysuperawesomelocalsite.dev

Comment: Here's a link to setting up a virtual host on your Mac in case it helps (suited for 10.8 and 10.9): http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I've moved the gem to my development group.  I assume since I'm not using it in production (I use passenger) it won't have any ill-effect when I do my next deployment to production?

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the suggestion.  I've let the app sit idle on my computer for 3 hours and came back to it.  No spinup time, it loaded immediately. :)

Comment: That's awesome! Very pleased to hear it's helped you out and have a great weekend!